# Discord Bot not responding to / command

Tags: discord.py, command, bots

I coded a small discord bot for our association, but can't seem to get the /clear command to work. I coded the command, so that you would type /clear and then a number after that. It works fine when deleting just one message, but when deleting 2 or more it just doesn't respond to the / command, but writes a message in a log channel, that the given amount of messages where deletet. Anyone got a solution for that?

```
@bot.tree.command(name="clear", description="Nachrichten löschen")
@commands.has_any_role('Dev', 'Admin')
async def clear(interaction: discord.Interaction, how_many: int):

    if how_many <= 0 or how_many > 100:
        error_embed = discord.Embed(
            title='Fehler',
            description='Die Anzahl der zu löschenden Nachrichten muss zwischen 1 und 100 liegen.',
            color=16711680,
        )
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=error_embed, ephemeral=True)
        return
    user_used = interaction.user

    # Begrenze die Anzahl der zu löschenden Nachrichten auf 100
    if how_many > 100:
        how_many = 100

    deleted = await interaction.channel.purge(limit=how_many)  
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

    clear_embed = discord.Embed(
        title='Nachrichten Gelöscht',
        description=f'Es wurden {len(deleted)} Nachricht(en) gelöscht.',  
        color=16711680,
        timestamp=datetime.datetime.now()
    )

    clear_embed.set_footer(text='Nachricht wird in #logs gespeichert!')

    channel = bot.get_channel(1113853971556225064)
    clear_who_embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Löschung!",
        description=f"Es wurden {how_many} Nachricht(en) gelöscht!",  
        color=16711680,
        timestamp=datetime.datetime.now()
    )
    clear_who_embed.add_field(
        name="Benutzer:",
        value=f"{user_used}"
    )

    channel = bot.get_channel(1113853971556225064)
    await channel.send(embed=clear_who_embed)
    await interaction.response.send_message("Erfolgreich!", ephemeral=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to `defer` your response?

```py
@bot.tree.command(name="clear", description="Nachrichten löschen")
@commands.has_any_role('Dev', 'Admin')
async def clear(interaction: discord.Interaction, how_many: int):
    await interaction.response.defer()

    # ...

    channel = bot.get_channel(1113853971556225064)
    await channel.send(embed=clear_who_embed)
    await interaction.followup.send("Erfolgreich!", ephemeral=True)
```

Your bot has 3 seconds to respond to the interaction with `interaction.response.send_message()` and since you are already just waiting 1 second in your code, the 2 remaining seconds may be not enough to clear those messages.

When you use `defer` you are acknowledging the response and can handle it later.

However, you can only respond to an interaction once, and the `defer` does count for a response, so instead of using `interaction.response.send_message` you will have to use a followup: `interaction.followup.send`.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=interaction%20response#discord.InteractionResponse